# Keep ORDER BY clause is invalid in view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL Statement:

```
Select CountryCodeTwoChar
FROM (Select CountryCodeTwoChar From [Country] Order By CountryName ) TBL
Where CountryCodeTwoChar = N'PS'
```

But I have the following Error from SQL Server:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR
>   XML is also specified.

I know it gave the error for the Statement:

```
Select CountryCodeTwoChar From [Country] Order By CountryName
```

But that is auto-generated by the system so I cannot change it!

How to re-write the statement keeping the statement there (Select CountryCodeTwoChar From [Country] Order By CountryName)?

{Edit}

I Tried the following, is that good?

```
declare @userData TABLE(
                    CountryCodeTwoChar varchar(30) NOT NULL
                   )
Insert into @userData
Select CountryCodeTwoChar From [Country] Order By CountryName

Select CountryCodeTwoChar FROM @userData Where CountryCodeTwoChar = N'PS'
```

Comment: `But that is auto-generated by the system so I cannot change it!` What system is that?

Comment: There is no need for the subselect. Select CountryCodeTwoChar from COuntry where countrycodetwochar = N'PS' order by countryname

Comment: My problem I have to keep this statement as is (Select CountryCodeTwoChar From [Country] Order By CountryName)

Comment: Well you can't. We can't solve problems which have impossible to satisfy constraints. (Although we'll often try :-))

Comment: Why do you have to keep it? We need more context.

Comment: The statement is used some where else in a system, and I receive that statement, and need to make sure some value is there within the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to re-write the statement keeping the statement there (Select
>   CountryCodeTwoChar From [Country] Order By CountryName)?

This will not be possible.  There is NO WAY you can use that exact statement in a derived table.  If you can't change it, you're out of luck.

If you are able to write multiple statements for a solution, so long as you use the exact statement above, then you can use that statement to populate a table variable, and then select from the table variable with your WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your workaround is good. The Optimizer will simply ignore the use of `order by` in this case because tables in a relational database are unsorted by nature - which is exactly the reason why you are not allowed to specify `order by` in a derived table or a view without also specifying `top` or `for xml` (and I'm guessing in later versions `for json` or `offset...fetch`, but too busy/lazy to check right now).

Answer (score -1):

Try and add TOP 100 PERCENT to the sub-select, That should help.

```
Select CountryCodeTwoChar
FROM (Select TOP 100 PERCENT 
CountryCodeTwoChar From [Country] 
Order By CountryName ) TBL
Where CountryCodeTwoChar = N'PS'
```

Comment: This is simply a hack to use an order by clause in a view - which does not work. The optimizer knows better and ignores it.